# Build Estimate from of Set of Multivariate Estimates based on Normal Distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let us assume there are a set of estimates, $\lbrace \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$, all based on associated multivariate Normal distributions of the form $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_i,\Sigma_i)$. The goal is to find a new estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_t$ based on the set of estimates and their distributions. I am thinking that I would like to find a new estimate that minimizes the trace of the covariance matrix for $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_t$.

How might I approach this problem? I have seen how to tackle this problem in the limited case of two estimates in a $\text{1-D}$ setting, but I am not sure how to approach it in a multivariate context with any number of estimates.